# How to access UITextFieldDelegate methods of a UITextFiled located in a container subview?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I created a container view via Storyboard, and placed UITextField inside. 
I can access UITableViewController directly from root view controller and set it's properties i.e. `containerController?.containerTextField.becomeFirstResponder()`. I also can implement protocol of container view controller in root UIViewController but still can't force to fire UITextFieldDelegate protocol methods with UITextField located inside UIContainerView.

This is a portion of container view controller code:

```
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    var aContainerDelegate = ContainerDelegate?()
    @IBOutlet weak var containerTextField: UITextField!
   (...)

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("textFieldShouldBeginEditing")
        textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
        return true
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("textFieldShouldReturn")
        return true
    }
}
```

I tried with and without UITextFieldDelegate declaration in root view controller -- it does not change anything.
Please, tell me, how to access UITextFieldDelegate methods of a UITextFiled located in a container subview?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just forgot to set `textField.delegate = self` in root controller.
The only problem exists: I can not set it directly when accessing container view at the first time in

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "containerSegue" {
            let dest = segue.destinationViewController as! ContainerViewController
            containerController = dest
            dest.aContainerDelegate = self
        }
    }
```

containerTextField seems to be not initialized at this moment thus `containerTextField.delegate = self` returns exception (nil value). I have found a workaround to set delegate in press button action, that shows and hides containerView.